# How do I setup a streamed set of SQL Inserts in Apache Camel

Tags: apache-camel

I have a file with over 3 million pipe-delimited rows that I want to insert into a database. Its a simple table (no normalisation required)

Setting up the route to watch for the file, read it in using streaming mode and split the lines is easy. Inserting rows into the table will also be a simple wiring job.

Question is: how can I do this using batched inserts? Lets say that 1000 rows is optimal.. given that the file is streamed how would the SQL component know that the stream had finished. Lets say the file had 3,000,001 records. How can I set Camel up to insert the last stray record?

Inserting the lines one at a time can be done - but this will be horribly slow.

Comment: In the end I could not go with Camel - using a timeout at the end feels flaky and I could not get it to work any other way. I resorted to a simple BufferedLineReader and Spring template with batching of 1000 rows at a time. Performance was very good indeed.

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend something like this:

```
from("file:....")
    .split("\n").streaming()
        .to("any work for individual level")
        .aggregate(body(), new MyAggregationStrategy().completionSize(1000).completionTimeout(50)
            .to(sql:......);
```

I didn't validate all the syntax, but the plan would be to grab the file split it with streams, then aggregate groups of 1000 and have a timeout to catch that last smaller group.  Those aggregated groups could simply make the body a list of strings or whatever format you will need for your batch sql insert.

Comment: Thanks. Thats what I am trying now. The tricky bit is detecting end of stream, using a timeout is OK but I am considering appended an end marker to the input file before processing so that I can detect that and set the appropriate header

Comment: The timeout does feel unclean. I wonder if anyone has a better a way?

Answer (score 1):

Here is more accurate example:

```
@Component
@Slf4j
public class SQLRoute extends RouteBuilder {

  @Autowired
  ListAggregationStrategy aggregationStrategy;

  @Override
  public void configure() throws Exception {
    from("timer://runOnce?repeatCount=1&delay=0")
        .to("sql:classpath:sql/orders.sql?outputType=StreamList")
        .split(body()).streaming()
          .aggregate(constant(1), aggregationStrategy).completionSize(1000).completionTimeout(500)
            .to("log:batch")
            .to("google-bigquery:google_project:import:orders")
          .end()
        .end();
  }

  @Component
  class ListAggregationStrategy implements AggregationStrategy {

    public Exchange aggregate(Exchange oldExchange, Exchange newExchange) {
      List rows = null;

      if (oldExchange == null) {
        // First row ->
        rows = new LinkedList();
        rows.add(newExchange.getMessage().getBody());
        newExchange.getMessage().setBody(rows);
        return newExchange;
      }

      rows = oldExchange.getIn().getBody(List.class);
      Map newRow = newExchange.getIn().getBody(Map.class);

      log.debug("Current rows count: {} ", rows.size());
      log.debug("Adding new row: {}", newRow);

      rows.add(newRow);
      oldExchange.getIn().setBody(rows);

      return oldExchange;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This one also has a timeout to "complete" the stream so to speak.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using the Camel-Spring-batch component. http://camel.apache.org/springbatch.html , the volume of commit per step can be defined by the commitInterval and the orchestration of the job is defined in a spring config. It works quite for well for usecases similar to your requirement. 
Here's a nice example from github : https://github.com/hekonsek/fuse-pocs/tree/master/fuse-pocs-springdm-springbatch/fuse-pocs-springdm-springbatch-bundle/src/main

Comment: Thanks for the reply but not sure how this solves my problem w.r.t streaming. How does a batch processing framework solve a streaming problem into the database? I know how to setup batching using regular Spring - it's embarrassingly easy to setup. But doing it whilst streaming from a file is not obvious to me.

Comment: Agreed these are 2 entirely different approaches, with the spring batch as a separate route and not from camel:file endpoint then the FlatFileItemReader : http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/2.1.x/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/file/FlatFileItemReader.html, streams the file, only when the streaming is completed the flow is handed to the processor, subsequently the writer which saves to the database, so this way the streaming issue is avoided.  However even not entirely sure how combining both the approaches will work.

Comment: I see. Unfortunately, I need the streaming approach because the file is only going to get bigger and I want to keep the VM size down. If I didnt need to worry about streaming I would simply use Bindy to put in a List and then send to a Processor to split into chunks for me. thanks